# California Community Colleges Transfer Data

Tags: data-request, education, state

Can someone point me to where I can find California Community Colleges transfer data?

Comment: What columns would the data have? Also, could you please give a few examples of rows? So that we get a better idea of what you are looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Datamart](http://datamart.cccco.edu/datamart.aspx) for the California Community Colleges. There are a variety of datasets to download, including the [transfer volume](http://datamart.cccco.edu/Outcomes/Student_Transfer_Volume.aspx) (to in-state private and out-of-state BA/BS programs) and [transfer velocity](http://datamart.cccco.edu/Outcomes/Transfer_Velocity.aspx) under student outcomes. For velocity, you can also choose by gender, ethnicity, and other attributes.

The system is a little awkward to use, but it does allow download in both CSV and Excel.

Bonus: The map of all the [California community colleges](http://data.ca.gov/2011/12/01/california-universities-and-colleges-maps/) is available at the [California open data site](http://data.ca.gov/).